# Can the papertrail gem insert audits in async?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I want to track changes to my models but I don't want to slow down my app by introducing more db calls. I wish to save audits in another database in async. Is it possible in Papertrail?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/the-battle-for-auditing-and-versioning-in-rails-audited-vs-paper-trail-17ad0011ecd9) post. It should be possible.

Comment: There's an open issue for this, if you'd like to help with it: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/1115